# Problems with TYPO3 installations version typo3_src-11.5.35.tar.gz

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

The installation guide is not easy for me to understand to install TYPO3.

The decompressed file was placed in the path /var/www/test. I create the FIRST_INSTALL file.

I create the database, the user is root and at the end it shows me that Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

I was investigating on other websites but I found the same detail.

It is difficult to install this tool.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have overseen the part of creating symlinks in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/Installation/LegacyInstallation.html):

```
3. Create the following symlinks in the document root: /var/www/site/$

    cd public
    ln -s ../typo3_src-11.5.x typo3_src
    ln -s typo3_src/index.php index.php
    ln -s typo3_src/typo3 typo3
```

Besides, you should *not* start a new project with TYPO3 v11 anymore. v11 is only in security-support (and this will end in October).
For new projects, please use v12 (or for bigger projects that will go live in some month, you may already take the coming v13)

Installing (and maintainer) a TYPO3 instance might be easier by using the recommended way of installation via composer: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Installation/Install.html

Comment: Good afternoon. Thank you for your answer.

Personally, I find TYPO3 very complicated to manage and configure.

I have a problem with the Forms section and it does not allow me to create forms and I have already searched and have not been able to fix this detail.

the message is No accessible form storage folders

Comment: You have already done "Include TypoScript sets"? https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/QuickStartForIntegrators/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out TYPO3 locally for experiments or learning you can try the DDEV installation of TYPO3 which is the recommended way to install TYPO3 locally you just need a few commands and you will get a working TYPO3 installing up and running without much to do.
Check here the recommended version of the DDEV installation.
https://get.typo3.org/version/11#version-download

Comment: Good afternoon. Thank you for your answer.

Personally, I find TYPO3 very complicated to manage and configure.

I have a problem with the Forms section and it does not allow me to create forms and I have already searched and have not been able to fix this detail.

the message is No accessible form storage folders

Comment: You mean edit button is disabled from for the forms in the form module?